# Keep running Update Function eventhough the game object is inactive

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi2,

Does anyone know how to keep a script running in an **inactivate** unity gameobject?

I have a certain *function* in *Update* that i want to keep eventhough the game object itself is inactive.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you could just stop the mesh from displaying the object, but continue to update it as if it was there ...

Comment: You have to have one gameObject which can handle the behaviour. Other way @BugFinder have already told.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) explicitly `is only called if the Behaviour is enabled.` Otherwise call it from elsewhere and not in `Update`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you reconsider your design.

Deactivating the whole object is specifically designed to remove the object from the world, without deleting it. It should no longer participate, in any form to the scene (as a side note, you'll notice that `GameObject.Find` will no longer find your deactivated object either).

You have some options though, starting with factoring out the bit of code you need to keep running while the object is deactivated:

Solution 1: As mentioned by mowie2, deactivate specific components. Put your bit of code in a different script, and deactivate all other components *except* this script that would keep running. This is a bit difficult as you'd have to iterate over all your components activating/deactivating them. Note: some components cannot be deactivated, like Rigidbody.

Solution 2: create a hierarchy:

```
MyObject (with component A, that must keep running)
 |-> Child (with component X, Y, Z)
```

In this case, you would deactivate the object `Child` (child would have all the regular components like Renderers, Colliders, etc.). MyObject would contain that bit of code that should keep running.

Solution 3: call update manually (as mentioned by Zambari) from another active script:

On your script that will be deactivated, add `public` in front of Update:

```
public class MyScript : Monobehaviour {
    public void Update() {
       // Your code here
    }
}
```

In another script that is attached to an active object:

```
public class AnotherScript : Monobehaviour {
   public MyScript OtherScript;

   void Update() {
      // Manually call update from this script, which is active
      OtherScript.Update();  
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice I like this idea!!!
Thank youuuu very much for your insight..! ^_^

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible directly, you can, however still call Update and other methods from outside (using another, active MonoBehaviour)

Comment: Thats sad..., I hope Unity will implement this option.
Regardless., Thank you very much for your reply @Zambari ..... ^_^

Comment: if I could spare your moment, would you care to accept the answer?

Comment: It defeats the purpose of disabling a gameObject only to call the methods on its script anyway. You can disable gameObjects, or you can disable individual components. If you want the gameObject to exist in the scene in any capacity whatsoever, you should be disabling the components you dont want. Not the gameObject. Unity will never implement this option because it is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @TheBatman there is a cost associated with having live gameobject, especially if it has a lot of child transforms - you cannot deactivate Transform compomnent without deactivating the gameObject. I personally use this method quite a lot to save on cycles and to make sure there are less callbacks running to those object. Speaking of which, I don't have the url handy but I you get quite a bit more performance by calling YourUpdate() instead of PInvoking the Update each time - if you have many objects

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to have two game objects. One that has the script you want to run, and the other that gets deactivated or activated.

The de-activatable object could be a child of the scripted Object, in which case we might consider it a "component" of the parent object.

The parent object now exhibits both features you were desiring. Access to the script while the game object is inactive.

How you divide the implementation between the two objects and there associated classes will reflect your particular application.

Enjoy

PS just noticed I am summarizing the 2nd approach of @kevernicus.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no. However, if I understand your problem well enough you might want to try deactivating individual components.

Answer (score -1):

You can get component **MeshRenderer** & set enable = false.
Process your logic in **update** function then set **MeshRenderer** enable = true